# Why doesnt the MVC4 bundling bundle Knockout.js?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-optimization

I have downloaded MVC4 and trying to work out how the bundling feature works in a standard project. It would seem that having the bundle:

```
<script src="@System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl("~/Scripts/js")"></script>
```

Brings back all the jquery.js files but not the knockout.js files in the included scripts. Why is this? And also what is the _references.js file about and why is the knockout.js file commented out?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you look into your project `Global.asax` file, you should find there something like this:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    ...
    BundleTable.Bundles.RegisterTemplateBundles();
}
```

Now the `RegisterTemplateBundles` is registering only a predefined subset of scripts:

- jquery-*
- jquery.mobile*
- jquery-ui*
- jquery.unobtrusive*
- jquery.validate*
- MicrosoftAjax.js
- MicrosoftMvc.js
- modernizr*
- AjaxLogin.js

If you want some additional files you could either change `RegisterTemplateBundles` to `EnableDefaultBundles`:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    ...
    BundleTable.Bundles.EnableDefaultBundles();
}
```

Or create your own custom bundle (you can read more about bundling and minification [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/11/27/new-bundling-and-minification-support-asp-net-4-5-series.aspx)). You should also know that `EnableDefaultBundles` has some performance impact.

The `_references.js` file is used by Visual Studio for JavaScript intellisense. You can learn more from following article:

- [JavaScript Intellisense in VS11, The _references.js File](http://gurustop.net/blog/javascript-js-intellisense-auto_complete-in-visual-studio-11-beta-the-web-_references-js-file/2012/03/03/)

Answer (score 2):

tpeczek is correct. Most folks don't use Knockout.js, that's why it's not included by default.  Bundling/Minification (BM) has changed considerably for RC and it will be much simpler to add files to bundles. See my [Bundling and Minification tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to add a file to the bundle with the following line of code added after the RegisterTemplateBundles()

```
BundleTable.Bundles.RegisterTemplateBundles();
BundleTable.Bundles.Where(x => x.Path == "~/Scripts/js").First().AddFile("~/scripts/knockout-2.0.0.js");
```